# Google Admin SDK authentication with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts, google-directory-api

My team is currently developing an application to list my company's domain users in GCP, using the Admin SDK, for onboarding and offboarding purposes.

We're using a service account to do this and we've have added the `admin.directory.user.readonly` scope, in the Google Admin's advanced settings, to it. The Admin SDK API is activated and we can see the service account in the Credentials area.

When we invoke the https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users endpoint with the parameters `viewType=domain_public` and `domain=[our domain]`, while using an access token generated with [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l), we receive the following message:

```
{
   "error": {
       "errors": [
           {
               "domain": "global",
               "reason": "forbidden",
               "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
           }
       ],
       "code": 403,
       "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
}
```

Could there be any domain restriction being applied that we don't have vision of?

Comment: I usually implement a longer flow so I'm going to give you an answer of which I'm not 100% sure. Of course your SA doesn't have rights to perform that operation on your domain. 
Go in the admin console and create a new admin role with the rights you need. Try to add your SA to that role.

Comment: Did you enable Domain Wide Delegation on the service account?

Comment: @JohnHanley we have tried this, but to no avail. Is this a requirement? Because from what I understood of it is that it's only needed for user impersonation and at no point in the documentation for the API does it say it's a requirement.

Comment: Yes, this is a requirement. A service account without Domain Wide Delegation has no rights to G Suite.

Comment: @Pievis none of the provided roles/permissions given by GCP cover anything related to the Admin SDK API. What roles are you referring to?

Comment: @JohnHanley Activating Domain-Wide Delegation did not fix our issue.

Comment: "Did not fix our issue". You need to enable delegation correctly. Either edit your question or create a new question with specifics.

Comment: Apart from activating domain-wide delegation, you also need to go to the admin console, Settings - > Manage API client access and provide your service account the necessary scopes (e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service account does not have permission to call Directory APi for your G Suite instance. What it does have access to do is act as a user in your domain within the context of the Directory API scope(s) you granted it access to.

When getting service account credentials you need to add the sub=admin@yourdomain.com parameter so that you are acting as your domain admin, not the service account. See:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

And some code examples at:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation